# How is it possible to vote a question without view?

Tags: support

I have seen a spam question view by only two users and got 7 down vote.

Is it possible to vote a question without view?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every post that is flagged as spam receives an automatic down-vote casted by our friend the [Community user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). The post has been flagged from the review queues.

That explains the 7 down-votes and the 2 views.

Comment: Great job.Thanks

Comment: @Smalution, I guess, sometimes there might happen 2 down-votes from the same user 
1)Flagged the post as spam by a user causes -1 to the post
2)Manual down-vote by the same user causes another -1

Comment: Yes you are right @Krishna Mohan. I have also seen many times.